# In focframework were can I get a list of all properties supported in config.properties file, and how to add my own properties to be used in my own

Tags: java, vaadin, properties-file

I am developing a web application using the full stack framework [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-Framework/framework), and I want to know what are the properties that I can control in my config.properties file. Is there a doc for this?

I tried searching the doc but dodn't find anything

Obviously we can figure out some of then from the [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/FOC-framework/foc.samples) by looking at the [config.properties](https://github.com/FOC-framework/foc.samples/blob/master/myfocapplication/properties/config.properties) file:

```
jdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:./myfocapplication_data_h2
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=

gui.rtl=0
allowAddInsideComboBox=0

focWebServerClassName=com.focframework.sample.myfocapplication.MyFocAppWebServer
dataSourceClass=b01.focDataSourceDB.FocDataSource_DB
cloudStorageClass=com.focCloudStorage.FocCloudStorageS3
cloudStorageClass=com.foc.cloudStorage.FocCloudStorage_LocalDisc

devMode=1
unitDevMode=0
unitAllowed=1

log.dir=c:/01barmaja/log
log.ConsoleActive=1
log.fileActive=1
log.popupExceptionDialog=1
log.dbRequest=1
log.dbSelect=1
debug.showStatusColumn=0
log.debug=1
perf.active=0
```

Is there any hint on how to get all of them? And what if I want to add my own to be used in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ConfigInfo.java](https://github.com/FOC-framework/framework/blob/master/foc/src/com/foc/ConfigInfo.java) file is the one responsible of reading all the properties and storing them in variables. It is straight forward to understand and check the variables names and usage. Yet I agree that someone should work on the documentation and add these parameters.

To add your own without modifying the ConfigInfo.java you can simply use this method in the middle of your code.

```
String myProperty = ConfigInfo.getProperty("my.property.with.a.meanignful.name");
```